# .NET Cookie Authentication : Call a web API from another web API

Tags: asp.net, httpcookie

I have 2 web API applications under same domain, Api A and Api B (.NET core5) configured with Cookie Authentication (and DataProtection).
From my Web application, I can authenticate to one of the two APIs, get the cookie, and can then call both APIs.

Now i wonder how it does work if the Web App calls an Api A Endpoint, and that endpoint calls an Api B endpoint.
Does the cookie automatically follow ?

```
[Web Page] => appCookie => {Api_A} => appCookie? => {Api_B}
```

Otherwise, how to make an authentificated called from {Api_A} to {Api_B} ?

Comment: When browser send request to server it sends all the cookie bot that domain. But for API to API call you need to read it from request (first api from browser) and add those in you second API call. `Rquest>Header.Add` may help you.

Comment: Hm I see, have to do it myself.  Is it a common behaviour or it is something that shouldn't be done, cookie authentication between APIs ?

Comment: if server to server you need to pass it explicitly it's a common behavior in my opinion.  But I may be wrong :)